# The content processing pipeline failed to process the item - SharePoint Search 2013 error

Tags: search, search-results, https

I'm having a problem with my Search Application in SharePoint 2013.

I can crawl successfully on `http` but not `https`. Below are the errors I'm facing.

The first one below is critical as I have no idea what it means.

> https The content processing pipeline failed to process the item. (
>   Cannot convert value 'System.Nullable 1[System.Guid][]' of type String
>   to a value of type GuidSystem.Nullable 1[System.Guid][]; ; SearchID
>
> http:// The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when
>   attempting to download the item.
>
> sts4:// The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when
>   requesting data from the web service.
>
> https:// The object was not found

Comment: Hi naijacoder,

It sounds like some sort of a mapping variable type issue.

A crawled property of a certain type needs to be mapped to the same type of managed property.
Maybe you have a crawled property of type Guid (Which I never encountered before) which can't be cast to a textual managed property.

That's just a hunch, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Pranav not sure myself as its a very generic error.Hoping if someone else has fix this error